# Is there a way to destructure data-attributes passed to a function onClick in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

**handleClick() is the function that i am trying to test :**

```
this.state = {
  expanded: {},
}     
handleClick = (e) => {
const { dataset } = e.target

this.setState((prevState) => ({
  expanded: {
    ...prevState.expanded,
    [dataset.id]: !prevState.expanded[dataset.id],
  },
}))}
```

**The handleClick function and dataId is passed as a prop to an Icon child component :**

```
<Icon
          icon={
            this.state.expanded[this.props.id] === false ? "plus" : "minus"
          }
          size="sm"
          dataId={this.props.id}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
```

**The handleClick() function is invoked when icon is pressed :**

```
const Icon = props => {
      const { icon, size, dataId = null, onClick = null } = props
      return (
               <i
                 className={`fa fa-${icon} fa-${size}`}
                 data-id={dataId}
                 onClick={onClick}
               />
             )
     }
```

**This is my Test case in jest for handleClick():**

```
it("should update state when handleClick is invoked", () => {
      const mockExpanded = {}
      mockExpanded[initialProps.id] = false
      wrapper.setState({ expanded: mockExpanded })

      const mockEvent = {
       target: wrapper.find("Icon").dive().find("i").debug(), //need to pass target value as 
       an object
      }
      wrapper.instance().handleClick(mockEvent)
      expect(wrapper.state().expanded[initialProps.id]).toBe(true)   })
```

**Even after passing the mockEvent as target object to the handleClick(e) it seems, the test case is unable to destructure the data-id attribute :**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

  27 |       expanded: {
  28 |         ...prevState.expanded,
> 29 |         [dataset.id]: !prevState.expanded[dataset.id],
     |                  ^
  30 |       },
  31 |     }))
  32 |   }
```

**Please suggest a way to destructure the dataset in jest test case or a proper way to test the handleClick(e) method.**

Comment: Does `mockEvent.target.dataset.id` exist in the test? This isn't destructuring, it is simply accessing properties of an object.

Comment: @Drew Reese Thanks for pointing it out. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it("should update state when handleClick is invoked", () => {
const mockExpanded = {}
mockExpanded[initialProps.id] = false
wrapper.setState({ expanded: mockExpanded })

const mockEvent = {
  target: { dataset: { id: initialProps.id } },
}
wrapper.instance().handleClick(mockEvent)

expect(wrapper.state().expanded[initialProps.id]).toBe(true)
```

})